# Display Data Chart.js with data in Html ( asp.net mvc using signalr )

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to put data from HTML to data in chart.js. Could you show me the way to do that? Thank you very much.

This is my query code in HomeController.cs :

```
public JsonResult Get()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValueConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [DeviceID],[Value] FROM [dbo].[Device1] WHERE [DeviceID]='PM1'", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    var listCus = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            DeviceID = (string)x["DeviceID"],
                            Value = (double)x["Value"],
                        }).ToList();
                    return Json(new { listCus = listCus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my text function to get data with signal :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Proxy created on the fly
        var cus = $.connection.cusHub;

        //Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke
        cus.client.displayValue = function () {
            getData();
        };

        //Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblValue');
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Get").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $.each(data.listCus, function (i, model) {
                    $tbl.append
                        (
                            '<h2>' + model.Value + '</h2>'
                        );
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And how I display data in HTML :

```
<h2 id="tblValue"></h2>
```

And now how can I put data from HTML to data in Chart.js code. Anyone can instruct me the way pls :

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("percent-chart2");
        if (ctx) {
            ctx.height = 209;
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            data: [ *, *, * ],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                '#00b5e9',
                                '#fa4251',
                                '#006400'
                            ],
                            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                '#00b5e9',
                                '#fa4251',
                                '#006400'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: [
                                0, 0, 0
                            ],
                            hoverBorderColor: [
                                'transparent',
                                'transparent',
                                'transparent'
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    labels: [
                        'STATION 1',
                        'STATION 2',
                        'STATION 3'
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    cutoutPercentage: 87,
                    animation: {
                        animateScale: true,
                        animateRotate: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        position: 'bottom',
                        labels: {
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontFamily: "Poppins,sans-serif"
                        }

                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        titleFontFamily: "Poppins",
                        xPadding: 15,
                        yPadding: 10,
                        caretPadding: 0,
                        bodyFontSize: 16,
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```